# Remote Desktop Gateway and slow performance

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

Some of my users are complaining that RDP performance is very bad. For instance scrolling results in a very a laggy experience.  They're connecting through windows 7 clients. I've tried reducing color bits but no change. I'm pretty sure it's not bandwidth related. Network latency seams good as well.

I personally have no problems with the performance when connecting from home. I'm not sure what i should do to troubleshoot this and find the cause.

Comment: Hi Lonely, Have you taken a look at the Connection Authorization Policies? Is redirection enabled or disabled? If it's Enabled, consider creating a new policy for your account and disable redirection, specifically for printers/clipboard. I've heard of cases where these 2 options can cause performance issues. Might be worth taking a look into

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to see if this is relevant. Anyhow I really need those to be redirected.